# Replacing a discontinued VanEE 20 min wall switch

Tags: switch, fans, air-exchanger

I've got a VanEE air exchanger with some extra exhaust fans in my basement (the original owner was a heavy cigar smoker who wanted to keep the basement pristine). In the basement bathroom, I had a vanee 20 minute switch (VanEE 20-Minute Lighted Push Button Part No. 1806110) which is discontinued on the official site and nowhere to be found online, at least not for anything like a decent sum.

I tried to get a Fantech RTS2 from Amazon, even asked in the queries section whether it would work as a replacement and was told it would, however, the RTS2 comes with only two contacts (my wall has 4 - black, white, red and green) and I tried it with black and white in both positions to no avail.

Before I return the fantech, if anyone has any experience replacing these Vanee switches with something that's still on the market, please advise on what to purchase and how to wire it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

https://www.markssupply.ca/ASSETS/DOCUMENTS/ITEMS/EN/vanEE_1806110_Installation_Sheet.pdf

[image] *(image from linked document)*

Indicates that the original switch had 3 contacts, **OL**, **OC**, and **I** (and describes using a 4-wire cable, but not using one wire.)

So, if you paid attention to what wires were connected to what terminals on the original switch, you will know which one to ignore and which three to try pairs of.

If not, you'll need to look at the other end of the wire where it connects to the ventilation unit:

[image] *(image from linked document)*

I will guess that **OC** and **I** activate the fan, and **OL** and **I** are for the "lighted" part of the lighted switch. That is, however, *just a guess*, since the documentation I've found does not actually say.

"Matching colors" without first sorting out what color is connected to what is not likely to work, especially with products from different makers. I presume the new switch is not lighted, so it would only need contacts to operate the fan.

Comment: The replacement switch mentions operation on 12VDC and "proprietary communication protocol" - I don't see that type of spec on the original switch. But you could try a voltmeter on the wires. Of course, depending on the specifics of the undocumented "proprietary communication protocol" used, it may not be as simple as a contact closure. Or it might be, and that's just obfuscation for the sake of selling complicated replacements for simple parts.

Comment: In one of the diagrams, NO is R. And C is G. But, "5.5 Electrical Connection to Optional Auxiliary Controls" (scroll down half way) uses OC, OL, and I. https://mans.io/files/fullviewer/553445 - Crossing two of the wires should make the fan run. Crossing the two wrong wires will pop the fuse on, or blow out, the board? If I had to guess, crossing OC and OL provides power to I. (that's what the Dehumidistat in the diagram would do, which is in series with a crank timer and up to 5 other things)